# How do I find the index of the greatest number of a matrix in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**m** -> My matrix

```
m = [[19, 17, 12], [6, 9, 3], [8, 11, 1], [18, 1, 12]]
```

**max** -> I already found the greatest number

```
max = 19
```

**Now I can't find the index**

```
for i in range(len(m)):
  for c in m[i]:
    if c==19:
       print(m.index(c))
```

**I got an error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#97>", line 4, in <module>
    print(m.index(c))
ValueError: 19 is not in list
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: `c` is the value. Not the index (it's not like javascript). Just do `print(c)`

Comment: you forgot indexing, m[i].index(c)

Answer (score 2):

From my personal "cheat sheet", or as proposed by "HS-nebula" the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.array([[1.3,3.4,0.1],[4.0,3.2,4.5]])

i, j = np.unravel_index(mat.argmax(), mat.shape)
print(mat[i][j])

# or the equivalent:
idx = np.unravel_index(mat.argmax(), mat.shape)
print(mat[idx])
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) you could just have `idx = np.unravel_index(...); print(mat[idx])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `numpy`. Here is a working code. With `numpy.array`, you can do many calculation from it.

```
import numpy as np
mar = np.array([[19, 17, 12], [6, 9, 3], [8, 11, 1], [18, 1, 12]])
# also OK with
# mar = [[19, 17, 12], [6, 9, 3], [8, 11, 1], [18, 1, 12]]
test_num = 19   # max(mar.flatten()) --> 19
for irow, row in enumerate(mar):
    #print(irow, row)
    for icol, col in enumerate(row):
        #print(icol, col)
        if col==test_num:
            print("** Index of {}(row,col): ".format(test_num), irow, icol)
```

The output will be:

```
** Index of 19(row,col):  0 0
```

And if you use `test_num = 11`, you will get `** Index of 11(row,col):  2 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need numpy you can do the search for max and search for the index at the same time.

```
m = [[19, 17, 12], [6, 9, 3], [8, 11, 1], [18, 1, 12]]
max_index_row = 0
max_index_col = 0
for i in range(len(m)):
  for ii in range(len(m[i])):
    if m[i][ii] > m[max_index_row][max_index_col]:
      max_index_row = i
      max_index_col = ii
print('max at '+str(max_index_row)+','+str(max_index_col)+'('+str(m[max_index_row][max_index_col])+')')
```

Output:
`max at 0,0(19)`
and with

`m = [[19, 17, 12], [20, 9, 3], [8, 11, 1], [18, 1, 12]]`

`max at 1,0(20)`

Answer (score 0):

This is way simpler using `numpy`. you can use the following to find the coordinates (xi, yi) of the maximum value in the matrix (array):

```py
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[19, 17, 12], [6, 9, 3], [8, 11, 1], [18, 1, 12]])
i = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(m), m.shape)
```